# CRm Dynamics 2013 How to change the colour of Chart bars based on Owner

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a Chart in CRM that list all open phone call activities of a 4 users in CRM, I am trying to modify the colors of the bars to be different for all 4 users, for example user 1 will be red, user 2 will be green and so on. I have tried exporting the chart and using the Chart Palette change the colours but I am unsuccessful, when I specify the colors I want it still display my chart as being the first colour I specified in the XML file, Please see my chart XML below

[image: XML Chart]

Please see my chart in CRm Below:

[image]

It defaults the colour to Blue, I need all owners to be different colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to have different colors if you only have a single series and category.

As a work-around you can add another category, which will result in colors being shown. The extra category should be something that makes sense to you.

For example, you can add and extra category of *Owning User* which results in the following chart (where the legend has been hidden with `isVisibleInLegend="false"`):

[image: Extra category: Owning User]

Alternatively you could add an extra category of *Created On*, which would result in the following chart:
[image: Extra category: Created On]